# Is there a better way to find the unique maximums in a 2d array in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, multidimensional-array, max

I have a 2d array of data that looks something like this:

```
import pprint
import jellyfish

data = [['', 'Sir', 'Arthur', 'Of', 'Camelot'],
        ['Sir', None, None, None, None],
        ['Amel', None, None, None, None],
        ['Of', None, None, None, None],
        ['Camelot', None, None, None, None],
        ['Art', None, None, None, None],
        ['Sir', None, None, None, None],
        ]

for i, name in enumerate(data[0][1:]):
    for others in data[1:]:
        others[i+1] = jellyfish.jaro_winkler(others[0], name)

for i, row in enumerate(data):
    if i < 1:
        print(('{:<8}'*5).format(*row))
    else:
        print(('{:<8}'+'{:<8.1f}'*4).format(*row))
```

**Output**:

```
        Sir     Arthur  Of      Camelot 
Sir     1.0     0.5     0.0     0.0     
Amel    0.0     0.5     0.0     0.7     
Of      0.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     
Camelot 0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     
Art     0.0     0.8     0.0     0.0  
Sir     1.0     0.5     0.0     0.0
```

What I'm looking for is the unique maximums. For instance, in this case I would like to see something like:

```
[Match(this_name='Sir', that_name='Sir', score=1.0),
 Match(this_name='Of', that_name='Of', score=1.0),
 Match(this_name='Camelot', that_name='Camelot', score=1.0),
 Match(this_name='Art', that_name='Arthur', score=0.8),
 ]
```

Note that `Amel` and the second `Sir` are missing. If I were to write out the process, it would look something like this:

- Look for the largest score (in our case, there are 4 `1.0`s so we'll just take the first one - `Sir` and `Sir`)
- Remove both row and column
- Find the next largest score (`Of` and `Of).
- Remove both row and column
- Find the next largest score (`Camelot` and `Camelot`)
- Remove both row and column
- Find the next largest score (`Art` and `Arthur`)
- Remove both row and column
- There are no more columns, we're done \o/

I've written a recursive form of this, which works, but it seems... ungainly. It may just be that this *is* the best way to solve the problem, it just feels awkward. In large part I think that's due to some of the restrictions:

- Either (or both) row or column could have the same name multiple times
- One name in the row can only correspond to one name in the columns

  - I don't have it represented here, but you might have two of the same names in the rows (or columns) that map to different names. For instance, if `Art` and `Amel` were gone, the second `Sir` would map to `Arthur`, so I don't think that a simple sort would do (e.g. you'd have two[or N] `(1.0, 'Sir', 'Sir')`).

Is there any better way to solve my problem?

Comment: Can you define *unique maximums*? PS And probably score should be `0.8` in the last `Match`?

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin ah, right. I say unique maximums because the pairing has to be unique. For instance, there are two `Sir`s in the row with a score of `1.0`. But we can only take one of them. And even if there were no other `Amel`, `Art`, or `Sir`, the first `Sir` could not match any other column because *it's* maximum is already `1.0` on `Sir`.